# Emergency Contacts

Tags: sql-server, azure

My project is to nightly upload employee next-of-kin details somewhere offsite in case of emergency. Security needs to be locked down to just three named users.

The data is already available in a VM SQL Server 2014 view.

My first bash, was to create a SQL Job to extract to CSV via BCP, then (step2) to upload to Azure file share via AZCopy.

I thought I'd nailed my first azure project ... but sadly this uses a shared access signature (appended to the URL) and not Azure AD, so I don't think this will do? (not sure)

Any ideas please?

Comment: What are your requirements? Where does the data need to be and in which format? Does it need to go to another SQL Server in Azure? If it does that's fine, just so we can help you with the right direction.

Comment: Hi Martyn, the brief is open. CSV's have been suggested, and a location that is not a VM SQL Server, or SQL Server in Azure. Azure Blob Storage was suggested.

Comment: you can use AAD with blob storage. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-storage-support-for-azure-ad-based-access-control-now-generally-available/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the data structured at the other end of your export then a flat-file as you suggested would work well and keep the complexity down. Shared signatures will work well, you just have to renew the signature when it expires. You'd have the same issue using Azure AD as well as the authentication token would just expire.

You could directly out of SQL Management Studio backup the full database to Azure Storage but this sounds like overkill for your requirements.

Another way to do it is by using Azure Data Factory, however, this has additional costs of executing the data pipeline to move your data and the complexity for a simple task.

Personally, the simplest way would be to export the data to a CSV on the file system, then have a scheduled task using PowerShell and put it up in your blob container in Azure Storage.

Comment: Thanks Martyn. But doesn't having a shared signature in the URL mean that anyone with the URL can access the data?

Comment: You can define IP addresses in the SAS, you can also use AAD authentication for this, you'll just need to log in when you run the script or task as it may expire your session.

Comment: Yes! I've an idea that the work I've already done (which works beautifully) is just part-1. Part-2 will be "users access control" (as apposed to azcopy access control), with a separate SAS key.